# Perguntas duplicadas com referência entre si

Tags: suporte

As vezes acontece de ter uma **pergunta duplicada**, seja por ter sido aberta 2x ou por pela mais antiga não ter sido resolvida, ou abertas por curto tempo de diferença, etc.

Mas as vezes acontece de alguém marcar a **pergunta nova como duplicada, referenciando a mais antiga**, mas também acontece de marcarem a mais **antiga como duplicada, referenciando a mais nova**.

Além disso, me parece, que acontece de marcarem **duplicadas entre si**, assim **ficando as 2 como duplicadas**, uma referenciando a outra.

---

Pergunto:

- Referenciar uma pergunta antiga como duplicada de uma nova, seria pela qualidade da pergunta? (pois não tem lógica uma antiga ser duplicada de uma nova)
- O StackOverflow não tem uma trava para não acontecer a "referência dupla"? (nova->antiga e antiga->nova ao mesmo tempo)

Comment: Há lógica uma antiga ser considerada duplicata de uma nova sim. Uma das definições de duplicata é: há uma resposta na outra pergunta (aka pergunta original) que responde a sua pergunta (aka pergunta duplicata). Isso às vezes acontece quando a pergunta que veio temporalmente depois é mais genérica do que a que veio antes, ou então ela é mais atrativo a resposta (não confundir com mais qualidade, existem outros fatores além da qualidade que podem atrair uma resposta)

Comment: Mas e o caso de ter referência dupla?